# R: select specific rows in csv file that have a value in first column

Tags: r, csv

I'm using R studio and I read a csv file.

The first column contains QP values, the second PSNR, the third FPS etc. I want to select all rows (containing QP, PSNR, FPS, etc values)  that has QP = 26.

My current code that read the csv file:

```
 UZL_H_C <- read.csv("test.csv")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `subset`

```
subset(UZL_H_C, QP==26)
```

---

Or if the dataset is really big, we can do this efficiently with `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(UZL_H_C, key='QP')[.(26)]
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you!